# Are there comparable-paying job prospects abroad for American senior developers who only speak English?

Tags: job-search, international

It seems like immigrants want to come to the U.S. because the I.T. jobs pay much more.  But sometimes Americans go to other countries for work despite only speaking English.  How rare is it for an opportunity to show up (outside of London, say Singapore, or New Zealand) that can pay comparable to what jobs in the USA pay?

Many multinational companies (e.g., in the biotech, software, defense and financial industries), have openings for English speaking people all around the world.  Is it worth applying, or will the job typically pay far less than what it would in an average part of the USA?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. First I guess there are differences between areas in the US already, and cost of life is also a thing...  there are many people living very well from their salary in IT in Europe at least. Now the language will really depend on your company. I work in Belgium and on the job I barely speak anything else than English for example

Comment: Anything over $100K PA earned in another country is taxable by the US Government. So you have to factor that in when determining your salary.

Comment: Guys I really think the OP is asking about making "a good, high, salary". OP is *not* asking about making, let's say, "a ridiculously high salary as is (sometimes) seen for programmers in the Valley".

Comment: Are you *willing* to learn the language, or do you think that requirement should be waved because you speak the de facto *technical* lingua franca? My job is well paid for Europe, but we regularly reject natural English speakers simply because they don't show the same willingness to learn the local language as for example East-European or Middle Eastern people have. Not all discussions are technical in nature, so local languages and customs are still important.

Answer (score 16):

> How rare is it for an opportunity to show up (outside of London, say Singapore, or New Zealand) that can pay comparable to what jobs in the USA pay?

I think one factor contributing here is what you can *do* with the money you get. In other countries compared to the US, you get less money, but you have better protection systems, whether it's healthcare, retirement or labor laws.

In short, if you are a healthy young white man and nothing unforeseen happens to you, there is little that compares to the US in terms of raking in raw money. However, the downside is that if you are *not* a healthy young man, maybe you are a woman that wants to have kids, or you are sick more often or your boss doesn't like you or maybe you *are* a healthy young man but break your leg on a skiing trip, there are not a lot of civilized countries where you can end up homeless and dying that easily.

Other countries have systems that protect all their citizens, no matter what. Or at least they try their best to do so, while in the US it's very much a winner/loser mentality. The right for everyone to not die of preventable causes is slandered as "socialism". You can go bankrupt and live on the streets if you get hit by a medical condition without fault, or even if something *is* your fault, other countries do believe that the community should stand in for you and help you out. That obviously comes at a price that you see in mandatory fees and taxes that are higher than in the US. Though if you take out the same insurances in the US, you would easily get to the same level if not more of your money being spent on it.

So, can you get the same amount of money than in the US say in Europe?

No. Probably in some rare situations, but as a general guideline, you cannot.

You do get a lot of other benefits though. Not all might be tangible. I heard the story of someone having had the same medical procedure I had just in the US. They were using it as an example of how doctors "prevent" the Opioid crisis in the US, telling me their doctor was "conservative" and only giving them opioids for two days, so they had to work all week and were only on painkillers on two days of that. Wow. Mind blown. When I had the very same procedure in Europe, I was told to get over the counter Ibuprofen from a pharmacy, but I had 7 days of fully paid medical leave as everybody here would have to rest and recover. I paid around 1€ for the painkillers and  0.35€ co-pay my health insurance has for the antibiotics. So one of us was in danger of being addicted to a deadly substance while having to work through it in pain, while the other was relaxing on the couch watching Netflix getting paid anyway. Things are different between the continents and not everything can be expressed in terms of raw money. I'm sure in terms of their bank account, they were ahead and proud of it.

IT jobs are well paid in Europe compared to other jobs, but they do not grant those large figures you know from US job ads. You will also have more taxes and more mandatory fees like health insurance. In Europe, you are part of a community, whether you want it or not, while in the US you are an individual and if you want to gamble on your health or home, you are free to do so.

So no. Raw money, you will not get such an offer here. If however, you actually use the benefits (lets say the wife is pregnant or someone gets real sick), you will probably end up with an equal sum of virtual money as if you had had the US salary and paid for all those benefits from your own pocket.

Comment: "...right for everyone to not die of preventable causes..." is quite the formulation, since the overwhelming majority of people who have ever lived have had it violated.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer to this is that you won't find a job outside of New York / Silicon Valley for which the the headline compensation figure is equivalent. That applies even to large chunks of America - you're not going to find a job in (say) rural Minnesota which pays as much as one in San Francisco.

But... it isn't necessarily the headline compensation figure you should be looking at. In either New York or Silicon Valley, you're either going to be paying a ridiculously stupid amount for a tiny apartment to live in, or you're going to have a nightmare commute (COVID excepted - I don't think anyone really knows what's going to happen with remote working when we're back to something more like normality). Then add to that taxes, healthcare costs and whatever else, and the difference between locales starts to close a lot. I'm in the UK but *personally* I'm much happier living outside London, getting paid a bit less but having more space to live for the same money, and better access to green spaces, but right outside my door and in easy driving range.

Comment: This is not really true. In high COL areas like SF where much of your paycheck goes to necessities like rent, food etc., the percentage that doesn't is likely to still be higher than what you'd make IN TOTAL after taxes in other countries.

Comment: Philip, regarding your first paragraph.  It's generally true for sure..  BUT there are a few notable exceptions.  For example, it's common that a quant has offices in all the major centers worldwide (HK, Dubai, Frankfurt etc) and they couldn't care less which city some superstar data guy (/huckster .. whatever) lives in, and the colossal pay is the same all over.  So, you know.  A handful (or less) of exceptions.

Comment: @Fattie Sure - but the question (title) refers to a "senior developer", not your 1 in 100 superstar.

Comment: actually yes @PhilipKendall you're totally right

Answer (score 1):

There may be other avenues, but one that is definitely viable is with grant projects in the third World or developing nations. Grants from World Bank, WHO, ICAO and that sort of outfit will utilise foreign consultants and pay very well.

Most overseas consultants here for instance make huge amounts and have hotel, food, and transport allowances, in some cases they're just given a house and car instead of hotel. Because they don't have the normal costs they would at home, they probably make much more than they would at home.

Answer (score 1):

Consultant and Infrastructure Engineer here for a New Zealand owned and operated software company currently doing business in NZ, Australia parts of the West coast of USA.

We'd happy pay $100k NZD for a good Senior Full Stack Web/.NET or Mobile Developer with leadership skills. Comes with flexible work arrangements, basic health insurance not the mention the lifestyle of living in arguable to greatest country in the world (I'm not biased honest).

We often just can't find enough good candidates here, so importing them from overseas or sponsoring someone with an existing residency application is always something we'd consider.

Amongst a good number of Kiwis our company currently has expats from UK, Canada, Sri Lanka, China, Turkey, India and we're shortly to add France to that list as well.

Comment: @PlayerOne, you must be living in Auckland then? Auckland is a whole different country to the rest of NZ! I'm in Chch and my commute is 25-30 mins TOTAL each day, including dropping kids at school (try that in Auckland or Sydney). Yes money is tight in our household, but I'm the sole income earner paying the mortgage, and supporting an extended family of 7.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it,

- (A) OP is asking about making "a good, high, salary".
- (B) OP is *not* asking about making, let's say, "a ridiculously high salary as is (sometimes) seen for programmers in the Valley".

Regarding A. Sure, there are plenty of places worldwide where you can find "a good, high, salary" just as in (a few places in) the US.  London, Switzerland, Singapore, HK, etc have already been mentioned.  And if you think in terms of industry, finance, banking, logistics, medical, etc., sure.

So sure, it's not "rare".

---

If you are asking about "B".  It's rarer but not unheard of. You'd be amazed how much money is floating around in Asia, Europe, the middle-east, etc. There are entrepreneurs and startups everywhere, and the most challenging technical niches are evenly priced globally. (Software is incredibly expensive, difficult software is ridiculously expensive, entrepreneurs have to deluge money in to make it happen.) However: that's more true of projects and contracts than "get a job".  Are there ridiculously-highly-paid projects and contracts<sup>†</sup> globally? Yes there are. Can you get a ridiculously-highly-paid "job" outside of the Valley ...... it's much less common.  {And again, only in a few exceptions like quants, financial, etc.}

*<sup>†</sup> And don't forget those only exist for really challenging niche technologies, etc.*